# Query to return concatenated result in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Consider the below table (name = keywords):

```
id keyword
-----------
1  apple mango
2  orange apple
3  fruit beans
```

I am searching for a query which is capable of producing result like below:

```
apple mango orange apple fruit beans
```

The query should just concatenate each row result and should just return a long string of concatenated result.

Comment: @Sashi - are you sure this has something to do with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :::

```
Select GROUP_CONCAT(keyword SEPARATOR ' ') from keywords
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loop to concatenate rows after retreving result